# Is it possible to get the width and height of a .gif file in scala?

Tags: image, scala, gif, filestream, javax.imageio

I am current taking in a .gif file through a file stream in an HTTP call, and I am trying to retrieve the .gif file's width and height through the ImageIO.read() function but it returns an error.

```
val inputStream = request.uploadedFiles.head.fileStream
val img : BufferedImage = ImageIO.read(inputStream)
val height = img.getHeight();
```

ERROR:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4096
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.gif.GIFImageReader.read(GIFImageReader.java:984) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1448) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1352) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Code?

Comment: I just added the code that I tried

Comment: does it fail this way on every .gif file, or only on certain .gif files?

Comment: I ended up using a gif decoder https://github.com/DhyanB/Open-Imaging from the link above ^ which solved my issue.